# how replace Spring Batch Admin by Spring Boot Admin

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-task

My straight question is: in Spring Batch Admin there is a clear concept and practical functionalities to manage the jobs. So, in Spring Batch Admin you can launch,  stop one job, stop all jobs, reatart, abandon, see the status for each job and check if it was successful or failed. In case I use Spring Cloud Task deployed as war and Spring Boot Admin deployed as war in same server, how can I manage my jobs?

Explaining better my context: I have developed few Spring Batch jobs in the last 6 months. All them were designed in order to run periodically, in other words, to be schedulled. I wasn't planned deploy them in Web Server but I was informed in my company in the moment to publish to production that I must run any solution inside of our Mainframe Websphere.

It wasn't any issue at all since I realized that I could use Spring Batch Admin in order to start/stop all the Spring Batch deployed in the same EAR. Unfortunately, Websphere ND 8.5 isn't comply with Spring Batch Admin (you may heard someone telling he/she has managed to make Spring Batch Admin up and running in Websphere 8.5 ND but I got the final position from IBM that neither JSR352 nor Spring Batch Admin is safe to be used).

One week ago, I firstly got in touch with Spring Boot Admin thanks to certain comment to my question [how to register org.springframework.integration.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39438251/how-to-register-org-springframework-integration-monitor-integrationmbeanexporter).

In such comment I read "...consider to get rid of batch-admin. This project is obsolete already in favor of cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-task..." however it doesn't seem to me to really provide the same functionalities Spring Batch Admin does. It seems to me be a bit more generic and aimed for application boxes instead of job executions.

To make my question even more clear, let's say I have this project deployed as war https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-task/blob/master/spring-cloud-task-samples/batch-job/src/main/java/io/spring/configuration/JobConfiguration.java and the two jobs are both schedulled for run every 5 minutes. Addtionally, in such project I added the necessary configuration to make it visible to Spring Boot Admin (e.g spring-boot-admin-starter-client). In the same server I have this Spring Boot Admin deployed as war too https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/tree/master/spring-boot-admin-samples/spring-boot-admin-sample-war. Now, my question that is the same from title but a bit more exemplified is: will I be able to stop one job and let the other keep running from Spring Boot Admin? Can I launch one and leave other stopped?

If you, reader, has an overview of Spring Batch Admin will probably understand quickly what is my intention. I read in th Spring Boot Admin manual
http://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/1.4.1/#jmx-bean-management
3.2. JMX-bean management "... To interact with JMX-beans in the admin UI you have to include Jolokia in your application". Is there some trick via Jolokia in order to manage each job individually?